# Finding closest key/value pair of ints compared to two other ints

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, lambda

I have a dict where each set of keys and values make up a range (2:6) and I need to find which set of key/value is closest to any given two numbers (another range)

Below is where I got to so far.

```
y_Start, y_Stop = min(dict.items(), key=lambda p: (p[0] - 8)  + (p[1] -12) )
```

I would like y_Start and y_stop to be the key/value pair from the dict which is the closest range to 8 and 12.

Comment: Can ranges in the dict overlap? Can the search params (the second range) overlap with ranges in the dict? Could you clarify the definition of "closest" in your context? Is the "stop" value inclusive or exclusive? How do you want to handle the situation where two ranges have the same distance? An example dict and a list of search params with corresponding desired outputs would also be helpful.

Comment: You should add an example input and expected output.